# How to set a foreignkey field in views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to save the customer field on the Test model, I'm not getting any errors but it's not saving the field either, how do I fix it?

Models

```
class Test(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

Forms

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ("email")

    def save(self, commit=False):
            # Creating the customer object
            Test.objects.create(email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
```

Views

```
def test_view(request):
    customer = request.user.customer

    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        customer = customer
        form.save()
```

Comment: Can i see your User and Customer models? Also, does your view work correctly? Cause it seems like it shouldn't

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cleaned_data` to save the ModelForm.

forms.py

```py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ["email"]
```

Assuming, you have request method `POST`.

views.py

```py
def test_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=TestForm(request.POST)
 
        customer = request.user.customer

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            test=Test(customer=customer,email=email)
            test.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ModelForm, then save the object without commiting, edit the customer of the object, then commit.

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ["email", ]
```

---

```
def test_view(request):
    customer = request.user.customer #I'm not sure this line is right, but I can't see all your models

    if form.is_valid():
        test = form.save(commit=False)
        test.customer = customer
        test.save()
```

Comment: getting this `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer'` for this line `test.customer`, any idea why the instance is returning none?

Comment: `customer = request.user.customer` here customer has a onetoone relationship with user